# How to make response.js markup mode work?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

[My example page](http://petripottonen.com/responsejs/)

If you scale your browser horizontally, you can see that the src of the `<img>` changes. So the src-mode is working ok. The code is:

`<img data-src0="mika.jpg" data-src481="jussi.jpeg" data-src1025="seppo.jpeg" />`

But I cannot figure out how to get the markup mode to work. 
Markup mode code that doesn't work (inside the div with black border on the example page):

`<div data-r320="markup @ 320+" data-r961="markup @ 961+">default</div>`

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear by adding the code that's not working. On the page that I linked, the src-mode is working but the markup-mode is not. How to make the markup code work also?

Answer (score 0):

In your body tag, change the prefixes to just be `"prefix": "r src"`. I don't know if it is a bug or not, but in my experience, the `min-width-` causes problems when its used with other prefixes.

I typically tend to just do everything with the `r` prefix. You don't really need to use `src` in your example. Just change em to `r` as well.

Some more examples not on responsejs.com:

https://github.com/ryanve/response.js/wiki/how-to-create-breakpoint-sets